# How to make Next.js Image component behave like a regular <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js

I have been fighting with this for a couple of hours and I have no idea what to do.

I have my Image component wrapped like this:

```html
<div className={styles.featureImgContainer}>
  <Image
    src={
      post.feature_image
    }
    alt={post.title}
    fill
    className={styles.featureImg}
  />
</div>
```

with the following styling:

```css
.featureImgContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
    
.featureImg {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

In this case, it is not taking full width of the container, because the height of the container limits the width of the image, so it can keep the aspect ratio.

[image]

When I shrink the viewport, the image finally takes the full width, but the height of the container leads to a creation of unnecessary margin on top and bottom:

[image]

The problem is, that if I remove the height from the image container or set it to auto, the image disappears. But this is exactly, what I want to achieve - have the width of the container and the image at 100% at all the times and adjust the height automatically.

With a regular < img > tag, I would just put it inside a container without specified height and define the width as 100%, and the height of the image would be automatically adjusted to maintain the aspect ratio and no white space would occur.

How can I make the Next.js Image component to work like that? I just want to put in my image with or without a container, without having to describe anything more than the desired width (100% in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the `fill` prop from the `<Image>` component, as per [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#fill):

> […] causes the image to fill the parent element […]

Instead, specify a sensible `width` and `height` prop (perhaps the expected dimensions at some arbitrary containing width), and then consider applying `width: 100%; height: auto` to have the image fill the parent width while scaling its height proportionally:

```css
.featureImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Remove the `height` declaration from the `.featureImgContainer` so that the element has `height: auto` and thus should get its height from the inner `<img>` element.

See this technique working in [the Next.js example](https://image-component.nextjs.gallery/responsive) and [its source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/image-component/pages/responsive.tsx).